# Simple app from Github - Can't connect to localhost

Tags: python, django, github

This is my project :
https://github.com/faisalshahbaz/django-calculator

Hi there. I'm a total beginner and I just need to run this app, but have no idea how to do it. Python, pip, django etc. all are installed. I cloned the app with Git. Created a virtualenv. Open the project with Vscode (Python extension installed as well), open the cmd and typed manage.py runserver  but only got this error:

```
C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\django-calculator>python manage.py runserver
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\django-calculator\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Mostly, it happens because you didn't get into the folder where the file manage.py is, look at the folder whre it exist and in your terminal type: cd name_of_your_folder after type: ls , you must be able to see the mange.py, from here you could run the server

Answer (score 1):

According  to your Github repository, you should first go to your django project i.e. **mainproject** so do `cd mainproject`. Then inside mainproject run `python manage.py runserver`